# BB10 android runtime push notification

Tags: blackberry-10, blackberry-android

I have followed [this tutorial](http://developer.blackberry.com/android/apisupport/creating_push-enabled_android_apps.html) to enable push notification on android runtime but
I am getting `failure 830 android/android.cfg: unknown asset` error when i try to deploy bar package into alpa device.

What can be the reason of that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solution is to change the way of importing android.cfg file into the android project.
First of all,

- add android.cfg file into root of the android project folder and
  rename it as projectname.cfg. For example, if the application name
  is SamplePushApp, the name of your cfg file must be  SamplePushApp.cfg.
- Secondly, sign your application using eclipse bar signer.
- After that, check out if the android.cfg file is created under bar
  file.